# Python Closing Toplevel Window Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, toplevel

I wanted this code to create a popup error window that destroys itself after 4 seconds but can also be closed via a button.

```
def error(self):
    top = Toplevel()
    top.after(4000, lambda: top.destroy())
    center_window(300,100, top)
    top.title("Error")
    Label(top, text="Please enter a valid code", height=3, width=200).pack()
    ok = Button(top, text="OK", command=top.destroy)
    ok.pack()
    ok.bind("<Return>", lambda a: top.destroy())
    ok.focus_set()
```

I have run the code and it works fine 90% of the time except sometimes it throws this error:

```
 TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I have done research that says it is Tkinters threading. I am not sure if this is my issue but when I take out this line of code:

```
top.after(4000, lambda: top.destroy())
```

It seems to work. If anyone could help me, I have taught myself what I know of python, so I am sure there are holes in my learning. I think I may need to somehow use the main thread of execution to destroy this window, or otherwise create my own custom widget. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with threading. Tkinter runs in a single thread at all times.

Answer (score 1):

When using after or bind, you don't need to use lambda.
Instead, for example, use:

```
top.after(4000, top.destroy)
```

which references the function top.destroy directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly bind the function to be called instead of using a lambda:

```
    top.after(4000, top.destroy)
...
    ok.bind("<Return>", top.destroy)
```

You would use a lambda, for instance, if you needed to pass arguments to the function; this is not the case here.